# Uploading a file into a Google Drive folder with PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have successfully uploaded a file into Google Drive. However, I'm still not sure on how to upload it into a folder. I need to upload it into a folder structure which looks like this:

```
Stats
    ACLLeauge
    ACLSydney
        Sorted
        Unsorted
            {Username}
                {FileHere}
```

The `{Username}` field is a variable that I will pass through. The `{FileHere}` field is where the image needs to go. Here is my current code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->instance = new \Google_Client();

    $this->instance->setApplicationName('DPStatsBot');
    $this->instance->setDeveloperKey(Config::getInstance()->getDriveDeveloperKey());
    $this->instance->setAuthConfigFile(Config::getInstance()->getClientSecret());
    $this->instance->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

    if(!file_exists(DP_STATS_BOT_DIR . '/' . Config::getInstance()->getAuthFile())) {
        Printer::write('Please navigate to this URL and authenticate with Google: ' . PHP_EOL .  $this->instance->createAuthUrl());
        Printer::raw('Authentication Code: ');

        $code = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        $token = $this->instance->authenticate($code);

        file_put_contents(DP_STATS_BOT_DIR . '/' . Config::getInstance()->getAuthFile(), $token);

        Printer::write('Saved auth token');

        $this->instance->setAccessToken($token);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->instance->setAccessToken(file_get_contents(DP_STATS_BOT_DIR . '/' . Config::getInstance()->getAuthFile()));
    }

    if($this->instance->isAccessTokenExpired())
    {
        $this->instance->refreshToken($this->instance->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents(DP_STATS_BOT_DIR . '/' . Config::getInstance()->getAuthFile(), $this->instance->getAccessToken());
    }

    $this->drive_instance = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->instance);
}

public function upload($image, $dpname)
{
    $file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle($dpname . '_' . RandomString::string() . '.jpg');

    $upload = $this->drive_instance->files->insert($file,
    [
        'data' => $image,
        'mimeType' => 'image/jpg',
        'uploadType' => 'media'
    ]);

    return $upload;
}
```

If anyone has a suggestion please tell me!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this you have insert the folders in the order you wanted. So add the Stats under the Drive root folder and then add all the folders in the order you needed. For adding a folder, you need to give `mimeType as 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) for more mimeType values. Here is an external referring [link](http://meu2rocks.blogspot.com/2013/08/php-code-for-creating-new-folder-in.html) on how to insert a folder in Drive.

After adding all the required folders you can now insert the actual file under the {Username} folder. You can also refer to this page on how to [insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-create#create_a_new_file_from_the_drive_ui) a file in Drive.

Hope that helps!